# Solving non linear system of equation

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Im wondering how to solve this system of equations?

$$\frac{2xy}{(1-x^2-y^2)^2}=0$$
$$\frac{-x^4-2x^2y^2+3x^2-y^4+y^2}{(1-x^2-y^2)^2}=0$$

Since they both have the same denominator maybe it's a good ide to use elimination? Or is there an easier approach to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The denominator is not allowed to be zero. For what values $(x,y)$ will the denominator become zero? All zeros lie on a circle around the origin with radius $1$. Can you formalize this? Let us call this set $D$ and the complementary set as $\bar{D}$.

**Edit:** In order to find the zeros of the denominator we set the denominator to zero.

$$(1-x^2-y^2)^2=0 \implies 1-x^2-y^2=0 \implies 1^2=x^2+y^2$$

The last expression describes a circle with radius $r=1$ which is centered at $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$. See the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations) for more information.

Then assume that $(x,y) \in \bar{D}$. Then you can multiply with the denominator, because it is never zero, after excluding all possible zeros.

Can you solve the system after this simplification? Use the first equation $xy=0$ as a starting point.

Comment: hm how can I see for what values (x,y) the denominator becomes zero? @MrYouMath

Comment: I added an edit.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying both equations with the denominators will give you two equations in polynomials with variables $x$ and $y$.

Solve these as you normally would. You then want to check for which of these solutions the denominator does not vanish.

Comment: could you please show me a solution? or a simpler example? I've been trying for an hour now and would really appretiate that :) @StefanvanderLugt

Comment: @Fanny If we multiply both equations with the denominators, we get the following two simpler equations: $2xy=0$ and $-x^4-2x^2y^2 + 3x^2 - y^4 + y^2 = 0$. The first equation yields $x=0$ or $y=0$. Substitute either of those into the second equation to obtain values for the second variable.
For example: if we substitute $x=0$ into the second equation, we get $-y^4 + y^2 = 0$. Solving this yields $y=0$, $y=1$ or $y=-1$, so from this substitution we get 3 solutions for $(x,y)$, namely $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$. Check for each of these if the denominator does not become zero.

Comment: okej I see but my textbook gives me a different answer. The same one I get by entering my problem here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=ae438682ce61743f90d4693c497621b7. witch gave me (0,0), (-sqrt(3),0) and (sqrt(3),0)

Comment: @Fanny The other two solutions are the solutions you get when you substitute $y=0$ into the second equation. The solutions $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$ we found earlier are not valid solutions to the initial equations, as for these solutions the denominators become zero.

Comment: oh sorry I obviosly did not read your comment properly. Thank you now I get it! @StefanvanderLugt